# Let $X \sim \mathsf{Poi}(\lambda)$, define $M=\max(2,X),$ calculate $E(X \mid M=2).$

Tags: probability

If $M=2$ then by definition $X\le2$, and so I tried plugging this into $$\sum_kkP_{X}(k), \quad \text{ for } \quad k=0,1,2$$ where $$P_{X}(k)=e^{-\lambda}\cdot\frac{{\lambda}^k}{k!}.$$ However, this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M = 2$, then $X \in \{0, 1, 2\}$:  Specifically,

$$\operatorname{E}[X \mid M = 2] = 0 \cdot \Pr[X = 0 \mid M = 2] + 1 \cdot \Pr[X = 1 \mid M = 2] + 2 \cdot \Pr[X = 2 \mid M = 2].$$

So how do we calculate the conditional probability $$\Pr[X = x \mid M = 2]$$ for $x = 1, 2$?  The idea is to use the definition of conditional probability:  $$\Pr[X = x \mid M = 2] = \frac{\Pr[(X = x) \cap (M = 2)]}{\Pr[M = 2]} = \frac{\Pr[(X = x) \cap (X \le 2)]}{\Pr[X \le 2]},$$ since you already noted that the event $M = 2$ means $X \le 2$.  So when $x = 1$ for example, this would give you
$$\Pr[X = 1 \mid M = 2] = \frac{\Pr[(X = 1) \cap (X \le 2)]}{\Pr[X \le 2]} = \frac{\Pr[X = 1]}{\Pr[X \le 2]} = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^1}{1!}}{e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^0}{0!} + e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^1}{1!} + e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^2}{2!}}.$$

I leave it to you as an exercise to finish the computation, and then letting $x = 2$, compute $\Pr[X = 2 \mid M = 2]$.  Notice we don't have to compute $\Pr[X = 0 \mid M = 2]$ since this probability is multiplied by $0$ in the calculation of the expectation.

Comment: So he meant "given that" and not division, as I understood.